# overflow-x: scroll, with position: sticky fix?

Tags: css, overflow, css-position, css-grid, sticky

I have a calendar, where I want the header, and the first column to be always on screen. Position sticky would make it work, if only it was not overflowing. overflow-x: scroll breaks the header, clip breaks the scroll. I'm out of ideas. I need the header and the content in one grid, so the header scrolls with the content. Codepen: https://codepen.io/qorinn/pen/bGQovNZ

```
` 
<div class="changeDate">
    <div class="back">
        <
    </div>
    <div class="thisWeek">
        2023/07/03 - 2023/07/07
    </div>
    <div class="forward">
        >
    </div>
</div>    
<div class="calendar-container">
    <section id="calendarSection">
     <!--divs by js-->
    </section>    
</div>
`
`
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.calendar-container{
    width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: clip;
}
section#calendarSection{
    margin-top: 25px;
    display: grid;
    background-color: #444;
    gap: 1px;
    grid-template-columns: min-content repeat(5, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(22, minmax(50px, 1fr));
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: clip;
}
section#calendarSection .grid-item{
    background-color: #efefef;
    cursor: pointer;
}
section#calendarSection .calendar-header{
    background-color: #fff;
    position: sticky;
    top: 25px;
    z-index: 8;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    height: 50px;
} 
section#calendarSection .start{
    background-color: #fff;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}  
.grid-item{
    background-color: #efefef; /*#007bff #28a745 #dc3545 #ffc107 #6c757d #17a2b8*/
}
.changeDate{
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: #efefef;
}
.back,
.forward{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
    padding: 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
`
```

I tried overflow-x: clip, but that breaks the scroll, and overflow-x: scroll breaks the position sticky. Also tried adding fix height to header. Checked other similar questions, but couldn't fix.

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed. You need to add a fixed height to the container (.calendarSection in this case). Note: for me it didn't work if I set the height to the exact height in pixel. Instead if I set it to 100vh, and the section overflows on the y axis too, and by adding an `overflow: scroll;` for the container, it works. For further details: https://uxdesign.cc/position-stuck-96c9f55d9526
Also check the Codepen for the updated code